What do I need to investigate? Is this sill plate rot, or varmites?
Help me please! I don't know what I'm looking at on top of my basement block wall, where the wood is soft and crumbly, and the pink insulation on the back of the paper was mostly gone. Is this animals, insects, or rot?
Does anyone know how to further identify what is going on and how this needs to be resolved? Thanks in advance!

Something has been gnawing at the wood .  You need to consult an exterminator.

Please use the built in image hosting. This site is transitioning away from using imgur, since their contract with them has ended.

it's rot.
I see damp. The wooden parts of buildings should stay dry. Fix this first.
